# How to determine if a point is within an ellipse?

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm having troubles finding the classic 'Contains' method which returns if a point is within a rectangle, ellipse or some other object. These objects are in a canvas.

I've tried VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates but I can't find the way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me. 
*(If you find it usefull please vote it!)

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9780672331985/graphics-with-windows-forms-and-gdiplus/ch17lev1sec22

```
 public bool Contains(Ellipse Ellipse, Point location)
        {
            Point center = new Point(
                  Canvas.GetLeft(Ellipse) + (Ellipse.Width / 2),
                  Canvas.GetTop(Ellipse) + (Ellipse.Height / 2));

            double _xRadius = Ellipse.Width / 2;
            double _yRadius = Ellipse.Height / 2;


            if (_xRadius <= 0.0 || _yRadius <= 0.0)
                return false;
            /* This is a more general form of the circle equation
             *
             * X^2/a^2 + Y^2/b^2 <= 1
             */

            Point normalized = new Point(location.X - center.X,
                                         location.Y - center.Y);

            return ((double)(normalized.X * normalized.X)
                     / (_xRadius * _xRadius)) + ((double)(normalized.Y * normalized.Y) / (_yRadius * _yRadius))
                <= 1.0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite so simple with C#.

First you need a [`GraphicsPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx). Then initialise it which the shape that you want, for an ellipse use the method [`AddEllipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xca09c0.aspx). Then use the [`IsVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25esxk64.aspx) method to check if your point is contained within the shape. You can test for arbitrary shapes by using one of the various `AddLine` methods.

eg.

```
Rectangle myEllipse = new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 50);
// use the bounding box of your ellipse instead
GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
myPath.AddEllipse(myEllipse);
bool pointWithinEllipse = myPath.IsVisible(40,30);
```

Comment: I don't know why you can't find it. But it's definitely there. There are quite a few tutorials online about using `GraphicsPath` with silverlight eg. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/graphics-path-in-silverlight/