# Defines Clickable zones in a Picturebox image - tooltips c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a picturebox with a loaded image in a Winform project in C#. I defined a Struct containing a few ellipses (X point, Y point, width, height, ZoneID, ZoneDescription) which I load into the Picturebox when I initialise the form.

I would like to try and do 2 things.
1) Allow the user to move with the mouse over the picture in the picturebox, and as soon as the mouse enters a zone identified in the struct, it should display a tooltip showing the ZoneDescription from the struct.

2) Then when the User clicks on any of the many zones it should generate a response whereby I can trap the ZoneID (which I already defined in the struct). I will then add this to a Dataset. This part I can do.

I just do not know how to go about Pt1.
I read somewhere I should define a MouseEnter Event handler and a MouseLeave EventHandler for ALL of the Zones, but I am not sure how to do that.
I already have a tooltip in place on the form.

**Here is the Struct Definition containing the Zones:**

```
 public struct TreatmentZone
    {

        public int nZoneID;
        public string sZoneCode;
        public string sZoneDesc;
        public Color sbPaintbrush;
        public int nZonewidth;
        public int nZoneheight;
        public int nZoneX;
        public int nZoneY;

        public TreatmentZone(int _ZoneID, string _sZoneCode,string _ZoneDesc, Color _sbBrush, int _ZoneX, int _ZoneY, int _Zonewidth, int _Zoneheight)
        {
            this.nZoneID = _ZoneID;
            this.sZoneCode = _sZoneCode;
            this.sZoneDesc = _ZoneDesc;
            this.sbPaintbrush = _sbBrush;
            this.nZoneX = _ZoneX;
            this.nZoneY = _ZoneY;
            this.nZonewidth = _Zonewidth;
            this.nZoneheight = _Zoneheight;

        }
    };
    TreatmentZone[] tZone = {
                                new TreatmentZone(1,"R1","Brain", Color.AliceBlue,155,35,30,20),
                                new TreatmentZone(5,"R2", "Hypothalamus", Color.AliceBlue,184,55,12,12)                                   
                                };
    private void pic_TreatmentZones1_RightSole_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(tZone[0].sbPaintbrush), tZone[0].nZoneX, tZone[0].nZoneY, tZone[0].nZonewidth, tZone[0].nZoneheight);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(tZone[1].sbPaintbrush), tZone[1].nZoneX, tZone[1].nZoneY, tZone[1].nZonewidth, tZone[1].nZoneheight);
    }
```

How would I do the required steps in Pt1? Does anyone have a Code Sample I can work with?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to subscribe to the MouseMove (for hoover) and Click Event of the PictureBox. You will then need to specify if the current cursor is over a treatment zone and handle this.

I have adopted your code and built a small demo.
Notice i have changed some names of your TreatmentZone variables to match the C# naming conventions. And also changed them to properties.

Notice: You will need to add a Tooltip to your Form.

```
public struct TreatmentZone
{
#region members

private readonly GraphicsPath path;

#endregion

//changed to properties

public int Id { get; private set; }
public string Code { get; private set; }
public string Description { get; private set; }
public Color Color { get; set; } 
public int Width { get; private set; }
public int Height { get; private set; }
public int X { get; private set; }
public int Y { get; private set; }

public TreatmentZone(int zoneId, string zoneCode, string description, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
  this.Id = zoneId;
  this.Code = zoneCode;
  this.Description = description;
  this.Color = color;
  this.X = x;
  this.Y = y;
  this.Width = width;
  this.Height = height;
  this.path = new GraphicsPath();

  //needed for hittest
  this.path.AddEllipse(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285007/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse
//This will check if the point (from mouse) is over ellips or not
public bool HitTest(Point point)
{
  var x = point.X - this.X;
  var y = point.Y - this.Y;
  return this.path.IsVisible(x, y);
}
```

}

And this is your Form:
Notice my PictureBox is just named to pictureBox1

public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

```
private readonly List<TreatmentZone> treatmentZones = new List<TreatmentZone>();

public Form1()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.treatmentZones.Add(new TreatmentZone(1, "a", "b", Color.Blue, 10, 10, 200, 400));
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var treatmentZone in this.treatmentZones)
  {
    using(var brush = new SolidBrush(treatmentZone.Color))
      e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, treatmentZone.X, treatmentZone.Y, treatmentZone.Width, treatmentZone.Height);
  }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var treatmentZone in this.treatmentZones)
  {
    if(treatmentZone.HitTest(e.Location))
      this.toolTip1.Show(treatmentZone.Description, this.pictureBox1, e.Location);
  }
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var location = this.pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
  foreach (var treatmentZone in this.treatmentZones)
  {
    if (treatmentZone.HitTest(location))
      MessageBox.Show("Handle the click of " + treatmentZone.Code + ".");
  }

}
```

}

Comment: Excellent Dear Feal! Thank you so much for your help with this! This will be really helpful! :-)

Comment: Hi all 
Many thanks for your help - I have incorporated your suggestions and I got it to work perfectly - also I use a List object now rather than a struct. Much better.

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of my exploration I have done it following this approach:
(Remember that this is a Desktop Application with Winforms)

1) Create a Picture Box and load a picture - in this case a png file.
2) Create a number of clickable zones on this image inside the picturebox using a List object. In my case I wanted oval shaped clickable zones.
3) The fields of the list object are loaded into a SQL table (or you could just manually load the list object as a Class - it's up to you)

Here is the Code I used:

The Class containing the Clickable Zones:

```
public class clsClickableZones
    {
        public int nZoneID { get; set; }
        public string sZoneCode { get; set; }
        public string sZoneDesc { get; set; }
        public System.Drawing.Color sbPaintbrush { get; set; }
        public int nZonewidth { get; set; }
        public int nZoneheight { get; set; }
        public int nZoneX { get; set; }
        public int nZoneY { get; set; }

    }
```

Then the implementation of this class.
On the Public Form event after the "InitialiseComponent" call I create a new call LoadClickableZones().

In this Form class I define the Listobject holding the values:

```
List<clsClickableZones> tZones = new List<clsClickableZones>();
```

Then I Load the Zones in this method:

Manually :

```
public void LoadClickableZone()
        {
            //this can now be loaded into table and pulled from dataset into class if so desired
            //Use Test Colour for visibility sbPaintbrush=Color.Bisque and Transparent for functionality
            System.Drawing.Color sbPCol = Color.Cornsilk;
            //System.Drawing.Color sbPCol = Color.Transparent;

            try
            {

            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 1, sZoneCode = "R1", sZoneDesc = "Zone 1", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 160, nZoneY = 30, nZonewidth = 25, nZoneheight = 20 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 2, sZoneCode = "R2", sZoneDesc = "Zone 2", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 184, nZoneY = 55, nZonewidth = 12, nZoneheight = 12 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 3, sZoneCode = "R3a", sZoneDesc = "Zone 3", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 160, nZoneY = 58, nZonewidth = 12, nZoneheight = 12 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 63, sZoneCode = "R3b", sZoneDesc = "Zone 4", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 177, nZoneY = 68, nZonewidth = 12, nZoneheight = 12 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 4, sZoneCode = "R4", sZoneDesc = "Zone 5", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 160, nZoneY = 90, nZonewidth = 25, nZoneheight = 15 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 5, sZoneCode = "R5", sZoneDesc = "Zone 6", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 160, nZoneY = 115, nZonewidth = 15, nZoneheight = 10 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 6, sZoneCode = "R6", sZoneDesc = "Zone 7", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 147, nZoneY = 80, nZonewidth = 10, nZoneheight = 10 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 7, sZoneCode = "R7", sZoneDesc = "Zone 8", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 186, nZoneY = 135, nZonewidth = 12, nZoneheight = 20 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 8, sZoneCode = "R8", sZoneDesc = "Zone 9", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 170, nZoneY = 145, nZonewidth = 20, nZoneheight = 30 });
            tZones.Add(new clsClickableZones() { nZoneID = 9, sZoneCode = "R9", sZoneDesc = "Zone 10", sbPaintbrush = sbPCol, nZoneX = 151, nZoneY = 180, nZonewidth = 33, nZoneheight = 20 });

catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error loading Zones", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
}
```

You could also just load all the Zones from a Table in SQL as follows:

```
public void LoadTreatmentZone_RSole()
        {
            //this can now be loaded into table and pulled from dataset into class if so desired
            //Use Test Colour for visibility sbPaintbrush=Color.Bisque and Transparent for functionality
            System.Drawing.Color sbPCol = Color.Cornsilk;
            //System.Drawing.Color sbPCol = Color.Transparent;

            try
            {
                string sSQL = "SELECT pkID, TreatmentAreaCode, TreatmentAreaDesc, ZoneX, ZoneY, ZoneH, ZoneW FROM myDB.lkMyZones ; ";
                Datafeed cData = new Datafeed();
                DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                cData.GetDataset(sSQL, ref dsData);
                cData = null;

                if (dsData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dsData.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        tZones.Add(new clsClickablesZones()
                        {
                            nZoneID = Convert.ToInt32(row["pkID"].ToString()),
                            sZoneCode = row["TreatmentAreaCode"].ToString(),
                            sZoneDesc = row["TreatmentAreaDesc"].ToString(),
                            sbPaintbrush = sbPCol,
                            nZoneX = Convert.ToInt32(row["ZoneX"].ToString()),
                            nZoneY = Convert.ToInt32(row["ZoneY"].ToString()),
                            nZonewidth = Convert.ToInt32(row["ZoneW"].ToString()),
                            nZoneheight = Convert.ToInt32(row["ZoneH"].ToString())
                        });
                    }
                }

                dsData = null;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error loading Treatment Zones - R Sole", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
}
```

Each Zone can now be clicked with a Click Event, or you can hover over it with a MouseMove Event as follows:

The Function for the Move/Click Event:

```
private int ZoneClickedRS(int mouseX, int mouseY,int ZoneArea)
        {


                    int ix;
                        for (ix = 0; ix < tZones.Count; ix++)
                        {
                            if ((mouseX >= tZones[ix].nZoneX) && (mouseX <= (tZones[ix].nZoneX + tZones[ix].nZonewidth)) &&
                        (mouseY >= tZones[ix].nZoneY) && (mouseY <= (tZones[ix].nZoneY + tZones[ix].nZoneheight)))
                                return ix;                          
                        }                       
                        break;   

            return NOT_IN_ZONE;

        }
```

The Calls are either from a MouseMove or MouseClick as follows:

```
private void pic_Zones_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int SelectedZoneID = ZoneClickedRS(e.X, e.Y,1);
            if (SelectedZoneID == NOT_IN_ZONE)
                return;
            string sZone = tZones[SelectedZoneID].sZoneDesc;
            miSelectedZoneID = tZones[SelectedZoneID].nZoneID; //Defined elsewhere

           // For Testing: 
           //MessageBox.Show("The selected Zone:" + sZone, "Selected Zone", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

Or for the MouseMove (Passes data to a ToolTip control as follows)

```
private void pic_Zones_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int SelectedZoneID = ZoneClickedRS(e.X, e.Y,1);
            string sZone = "";

            if (SelectedZoneID == NOT_IN_ZONE)

                tipZoneArea.RemoveAll();
            else
                sZone = tZones[SelectedZoneID].sZoneDesc;
            tipZoneArea.SetToolTip(pic_Zones, "Clicked" + sZone);

        }
```

Finally to make the Zones visible on your Picture Box you have this call:

```
private void pic_Zones__Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            int ii;
            for (ii = 0; ii < tZones.Count; ii++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(tZones[ii].sbPaintbrush), tZones[ii].nZoneX, tZones[ii].nZoneY, tZones[ii].nZonewidth, tZones[ii].nZoneheight);
            }               

        }
```